# Trying to hide the select input and footer elements of Calendar in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, antd

I'm working with a DatePicker element in Antd and I'm trying to only show the calendar body.

I've tried using styled components to directly target the header and footer of the calendar and set `display: none;` properties on both, but so far no dice.

[**Antd Library**](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#components-date-picker-demo-basic)

[image: Edit elastic-gould-1lcs6]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import styled from "styled-components";

function onChange(value, dateString) {
  console.log("Selected Time: ", value);
  console.log("Formatted Selected Time: ", dateString);
}

function onOk(value) {
  console.log("onOk: ", value);
}

const StyledDatePicker = styled(DatePicker)`
  &&& {
    .ant-calendar-input {
      display: none;
    }

    .ant-calendar-footer {
      display: none;
    }
  }
`;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <StyledDatePicker
      open
      placeholder="Select Time"
      onChange={onChange}
      onOk={onOk}
    />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Comment: Link us to the component library so we can see what you're using.

Comment: Just updated the original question with a link to the library

Comment: I'm trying to edit the DatePicker specifically because the ```open``` calendar is the exact style I need minus the select input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure CSS will suffice for this; no need to create a new styled component:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-framework-89gwd

**CSS**

```
.my-class,
.ant-calendar-input-wrap,
.ant-calendar-footer {
  display: none;
}
```

**Component**

```
<DatePicker
  open
  className="my-class"
  placeholder="Select Time"
  onChange={onChange}
  onOk={onOk}
/>
```

Comment: Nice! I'm trying to apply the same styles via a styled component and it's not working. Do you know why that is? Here's an updated Code Sandbox to show what I mean: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-currying-csgtr?fontsize=14

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because this component is part of a larger application that uses styled components and a theme for styling and we're not using css files

Comment: @Josh I don't think this is possible given how `DatePicker` renders itself in the DOM. Open the DOM Inspector, and find your `container` element that is being mounted, then find your `Col` element. Note that it does not contain the full `DatePicker` element, but part of the input field. Now collapse the `container` element, and look below it, you'll see the actual `DatePicker` component being rendered in full; meaning your styles are only accessible from within the `container` hierarchy. Not sure why they chose to write the component like this.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. It's a bummer but it makes sense haha. Thanks for the help